# listener for pressing and releasing a button

Tags: android, view

How can I listen for when a `Button` is pressed and released?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use a `onTouchListener`:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // RELEASED
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` event also should be handled as button release event (the same way as `ACTION_UP`) as it is fired when you perform some gesture after pressing button (`ACTION_UP` event is not fired in this case).

Comment: If anyone's wondering, on a regular View, these don't correspond to `ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS` and `ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE`. Thought those two might encompass the `DOWN`, `UP` and `CANCEL` actions.

Comment: But this blocks `onClickListener`

Comment: If you are consuming the event, you should also invoke performClick() on the view.

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko You can add  `v.performClick()`  in `ACTION_UP`  case if needed, or just `return false`.

Answer (score 12):

The answer given by [fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11779177) is correct for generic views.

For a `Button`, you should return `false` from the touch handler *always*:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {      
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // RELEASED
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you return `true` you will circumvent the button's regular touch processing. Which means you will loose the visual effects of pressing the button down and the touch ripple. Also, `Button#isPressed()` will return `false` while the button is actually pressed.

The button's regular touch processing will ensure that you get the follow-up events even when returning `false`.

Answer (score 4):

[`onTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) is what you are looking for.

You will need to use the correct [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

This will allow you to handle the different types of "touches".