# Android: How can I call a method after a view touched

Tags: android, methods, selector

I want to call a method after my button get touched and call another method after touch finished,
is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code it May help you

```
yourButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have some research to do. What kind of view do you have? You need something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Call your method here
}
```

But it is impossible to know what exactly you need, without knowing anything about what you are doing.

EDIT: You changed your question. [This is what you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11779177/4600745)