# How to send a stream of characters on long press of button

Tags: android, android-button

How to send a stream of characters on long press of the button. 
Here is the code for on LongClick of button,

```
btnDown.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            sendMessage("S");//Here I wanted to send for example SSSSS on long press of that button
        }
    });
```

I want to send a stream of character on long press of a button until the user releases the button.

Comment: DId you consider having touch down and up actions?

Comment: Nope. I am having buttons. On click of buttons I need to perform this action.

Comment: You can easily add an on touch listener to the button . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779082/listener-for-pressing-and-releasing-a-button

Comment: That's fine. I can use click ClickListeners for buttons, But my question is, how to send stream of characters on long press of a button

Answer (score 2):

Try Like This make custom `Listner`

```
    String mString="";

public class ContinousRepeatListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private int initialInterval;
private final int normalInterval;
private final View.OnClickListener clickListener;

private Runnable handlerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, normalInterval);
        clickListener.onClick(downView);
    }
};

private View downView;

/**
 * @param initialInterval The interval after first click event
 * @param normalInterval The interval after second and subsequent click 
 *       events
 * @param clickListener The OnClickListener, that will be called
 *       periodically
 */
public ContinousRepeatListener (int initialInterval, int normalInterval, 
        View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
    if (clickListener == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null runnable");
    if (initialInterval < 0 || normalInterval < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative interval");

    this.initialInterval = initialInterval;
    this.normalInterval = normalInterval;
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
        handler.postDelayed(handlerRunnable, initialInterval);
        downView = view;
        downView.setPressed(true);
        clickListener.onClick(view);
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
        downView.setPressed(false);
        downView = null;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

and Use like this

```
 btnDown.setOnTouchListener(new ContinousRepeatListener(400, 100, new  View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // the code to execute repeatedly
            mString += "S";
            tvString.setText(mString);
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Everytime the string length is 736, Long click is not happening. I want the button to work same as keyboard keys work.

Answer (score 0):

Use setOnTouchListener and on ACTION_DOWN write your sendMessage code

Comment: I am having 4 buttons, like left, right,down and up. Is there is way to do using `LongClickListeners` ?